# Is it possible to execute automation maven project from Azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines

I have built an automation framework using Java, Selenium Webdriver, Maven, TestNG. Currently, I am using Jenkins for pipeline and CI.

Now new requirement assigned to me is using Azure DevOps as CI tool and execute all test from there instead of Jenkins.

After some research, I am getting the following :

1. Upload code to Github or other azure supported repo. and create a pipeline.
2. Write your Java code using Visual studio code and then it will be far easy to execute from  Azure DevOps.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to write your code in VisualStudioCode in order to get it executed more easily in DevOps, you can use whatever you are using now. there is a maven-task in DevOps so i'd guess you could run maven-projects in DevOps

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow steps below. Main effort is of tools integration if those are not present in azure devops portal :

1. I am not sure which code repository you are using however if you are not using one which is supported by Azure devops, then you need integrate it with azure devops portal.
2. Create agentpool in azure devops  with same configuration as your jenkins agent.
3. Create build pipeline in azure devops.  It will ask your repository name . Give the same. 
   4.While Creating pipeline it will ask you whether to create azure pipline yaml or not . Say "Yes"  and it will create sample yaml file in code repository.
4. Open Yaml file.

   - give your agentpool name  where they have mentioned it.
   - under section " steps " 
     mention all steps which you want to do run test cases. you would mentioned same 
     thing is jenkins pipeline under stages --> steps like shell '''   '''
5. save yaml and run it. you are done

NOTE : Main thing is configuration of agentpool. you need to make it should have all software tools ( except jenkin agent jar :) ).

Comment: Hi, In this case if I want to remove jenkins from whole concept and want to directly deal with azure devops, still I can use same steps with agent pool?

Comment: Yes. Correct.  No jenkins needed. For E.g.  if you are using curl command in jenkins pipeline , write the same curl command in yaml under section " steps " and you are done